# Conditional Format Issue

Tags: ms-access-2003

I am having difficulty with a conditional format of a form.  I have three conditions and two work.

[image]

Conditions 2 & 3 work fine.  Condition 1 is another story.  I have added condition one after I knew 2 & 3 were working.  I basically added a 3rd condition then swapped 1 for 3 out of fear that after condition one was met the conditions stopped.  Now condition 1 is the primary.  What have I done wrong for condition 1 not to show?

Comment: Detail is a part of a form and of a report. Do you have a control called detail? If so, rename it to say txtDetail and see if that works.

Comment: Remou, I need to remember to keep it simple...  You were exactly right.  The text box was Named "Detail1"  I had renamed the caption Detail...  I forgot that the [] refers to the Name not the caption...  Once again you are my hero! Thanks

Comment: Could you please share the conditions?